# PHP and Wildfly communication

Tags: php, web-services, jboss, wildfly-8, php-java-bridge

I would like to query Wildfly from PHP. I would like to query Wildfly sometimes depending on the user input - not for all user input. For example when a user send a request, the PHP script should extract the request parameters and depending on these parameters I need to query.

What are the best/common strategies to make **fast communication** with Wildfly from PHP? I have seen `mod_jk`, `mod_cluster` I am wondering if I need to install them for this purpose. Please help don't close the thread. I am not PHP or java expert. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

AJP connection between Apache HTTP Server and WildFly AJP connector would do -- you may use either mod_proxy_ajp for a static, simple scenarios or you could leverage mod_cluster if you have WildFly servers coming and going and you need a proper load balancing and high-availability service.